# Sleep Display Cocoa/Carbon

Tags: cocoa, xcode, macos, macos-carbon

I'm trying to make my application sleep the screen.

I've looked into pmset with no success and I even tried IOHIDPostEvent. I can get IOHIDPostEvent to press the Eject key but setting the shift and control flags has no effect.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't believe there is a public API yet (please file a bug), but some code is [here](http://explanatorygap.net/2009/01/31/a-screensaver-to-send-your-display-to-sleep/).